# How can extract elements from a cell array

Tags: matlab

Let's say: Cell A with size of 1x10 cell:

```
A={1x10} cell
```

And the size each matrix in the cell A is like this:

```
{A}={ [A1] [A2] [A3] [A4] [A5] [A6] [A7] ............ [A10] }
{A}={ [5000x3  double] [3000x3  double] ......... [2222x3 double] }
```

How can extract each matrix (A1,A2,A3....,A10) from a cell A?

THANKS,

Comment: `A{i}` extracts the i-th matrix.

Comment: Thank. If I want to plot in 3d all matrix Ai (1 matrix with 1 color) in only 1 Figure, How can I plot? Example: A1 contain 5000 pts with (x y z) coordinate. A2 contain 3000 pts with (x y z) coordinate....,so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in detail in matlab documentation [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html), you can use curly braces to extract items from a cell array, if you wish for the result to be a simple array and not a cell.

Thus A{2} would give you matrix A2.

Comment: Thank. If I want to plot in 3d all matrix Ai (1 matrix with 1 color)  in only 1 Figure , How can I plot? Example: A1 contain 5000 pts with (x y z) coordinate. A2 contain 3000 pts with (x y z) coordinate....,so on

Comment: Comments are not the place for completely new questions, even if related to the original question. If you really get stuck then ask a new question, but in the meantime I'd recommend investigating the 'graphics' section of the inbuilt documentation